# Prove that an equation for $L$ is $(\cos\theta)x+(\sin\theta)y=p.$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $L$ be a line and $N$ a point in $L$ such that $\overrightarrow{ON}$ is a normal vector to $L$. Prove that an equation for $L$ is $$(\cos\theta)x+(\sin\theta)y=p$$
where $p=\|\overrightarrow{ON}\|$ and $\theta$ is the direction of $\overrightarrow{ON}.$

**Try:**

We know that if $\overrightarrow{N}=(a,b)$ is a normal vector to $L$, then an equation for $L$ is $ax+by=c$. So the only thing I have to prove is $\overrightarrow{ON}=(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$ with $\alpha$ the direction of $\overrightarrow{ON}$, but how can I do that. Any help or it's already Of course $\overrightarrow{ON}$ can be written like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector $$(a,b):=\frac1p\,\overrightarrow{ON}=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$$ is also normal to $L$ hence (applying what you said you know) there exists a $c$ such that the equation of $L$ is $$ax+by=c.$$

Since moreover $N=(pa,pb)\in L,$
$$\begin{align}c&=a(pa)+b(pb)\\&=p\left(a^2+b^2\right)\\&=p,\end{align}
$$
which ends the proof.

Alternatively (without applying what you said you know): a point $M=(x,y)$ belongs to $L$ iff $\overrightarrow{NM}\cdot\frac1p\overrightarrow{ON}=0,$ i.e.
$$\begin{align}0&=\left(x-pa\right)a+\left(y-pb\right)b\\
&=ax+by-p\left(a^2+b^2\right)\\
&=ax+by-p.
\end{align}$$

Comment: There is probably at least one duplicate but I was not able to find any.